# Hidden Message: 5 Papers

Tags: cipher

okay this is the scenario this time;

A rebel member was captured in order to intercept a message. There are several items he was carrying on him; his wallet, house key, an old mobile phone, and 5 piece of papers (as shown below). Figure out what is the message he was carrying.

[image: paper5]
[image: paper1]
[image: paper3]
[image: paper4]
[image: paper2]

There's something else needed to solve the puzzle, but what it is, is already hinted. You can also use an image editing software for help, although not really needed. The final answer will be in text form (words).

Sorry for a really long post, I need to use quite a number of images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The message is**:

> Destroy west area tonight.

Gather all of the blocks by label, read clockwise. The numbers are (key number. position on key) for old style mobile phones.

Edit:
Ignore the first piece of paper. For the other pieces, arrange them to form a complete shape out of the 4 segments labelled '1'. Record, in order (starting from top left), the red numbers running around the outside.

> (3.1, 3.2, 7.4, 8.1, 7.3, 6.3, 9.3).

Repeat this for segments labelled '2', '3' and '4', giving you:

> (9.1, 3.2, 7.4, 8.1)
>
> (2.1, 7.3, 3.2, 2.1)
>
> (8.1, 6.3, 6.2, 4.3, 4.1, 4.2, 8.1)

Examining these, you'll notice that the first digit is 2-9 and the second is 1-4, which calls to mind old style phone keypads (particularly when one was mentioned in the question). The first number is which key to look at, the second number is which letter on that key is meant. So 3.2 means 3rd key ('def'), second letter:'e'

Working through the list:

> we get 'destroy west area tonight'.

Comment: Wow, that fast eh... Was it too direct?

Comment: I don't think so; I just happened to go looking for a new puzzle as you posted this. Thanks for the puzzle.

Comment: I finally got it, but perhaps you could expand this answer more to help those that can't.

Comment: @istrasci I've edited the answer to be clearer. Let me know if it still requires explanation.